# Pattern matching with associative and commutative operators

Tags: language-agnostic, pattern-matching, theorem-proving

Pattern matching (as found in e.g. Prolog, the ML family languages and various expert system shells) normally operates by matching a query against data element by element in strict order.

In domains like automated theorem proving, however, there is a requirement to take into account that some operators are associative and commutative. Suppose we have data

```
A or B or C
```

and query

```
C or $X
```

Going by surface syntax this doesn't match, but logically it should match with `$X` bound to `A or B` because `or` is associative and commutative.

Is there any existing system, in any language, that does this sort of thing?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your conflation of Prolog pattern matching vs. ML pattern matching.  ML pattern matching is purely syntactic, and in Prolog I don't believe this is the case.

Comment: I'm not saying they're the same thing, only that they have in common the comparison of elements in strict order.

Comment: I'd assume dedicated theorem proving software like Otter already does this by placing logical formulas in a normal form and treating the clauses as set data structures, which costs O(n log n) time for both creation and verification.  In fact, I'd assume they've preprogrammed optimizations for operations for properties like associativity and commutativity.

Comment: Yes, I've done the same myself in theorem proving code that worked similarly to Otter. What I'm looking at now is implementing something somewhat more general than that special-case hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Associative-Commutative pattern matching has been around since [1981 and earlier](http://basics.sjtu.edu.cn/~liguoqiang/teaching/algo11/materials/AC.pdf), and is still a hot topic [today](http://users.dsic.upv.es/workshops/wrs2011/pre-proceedings.pdf).

There are lots of systems that implement this idea and make it useful; it means you can avoid write complicated pattern matches when associtivity or commutativity could be used to make the pattern match.  Yes, it can be expensive; better the pattern matcher do this automatically, than you do it badly by hand.

You can see an example in a [rewrite system for algebra and simple calculus](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html) implemented using our program transformation system.  In this example, the symbolic language to be processed is defined by grammar rules, and those rules that have A-C properties are marked.  Rewrites on trees produced by parsing the symbolic language are automatically extended to match.

Comment: The links in your first sentence are dead now, but interested readers can still access the PDFs through the Internet Archive:
[1] http://web.archive.org/web/20120619184235/http://basics.sjtu.edu.cn/~liguoqiang/teaching/algo11/materials/AC.pdf
[2] http://web.archive.org/web/20120706040706/http://users.dsic.upv.es/workshops/wrs2011/pre-proceedings.pdf

Answer (score 6):

The maude term rewriter implements associative and commutative pattern matching.

http://maude.cs.uiuc.edu/

Comment: could you give a more specific link? perhaps with a code example?

Answer (score 1):

I've never encountered such a thing, and I just had a more detailed look.

There is a sound computational reason for not implementing this by default - one has to essentially generate all combinations of the input before pattern matching, or you have to generate the full cross-product worth of match clauses.

I suspect that the usual way to implement this would be to simply write both patterns (in the binary case), i.e., have patterns for both `C or $X` and `$X or C`.

Depending on the underlying organisation of data (it's usually tuples), this pattern matching would involve rearranging the order of tuple elements, which would be weird (particularly in a strongly typed environment!).  If it's lists instead, then you're on even shakier ground.

Incidentally, I suspect that the operation you fundamentally want is disjoint union patterns on sets, e.g.:

```
foo (Or ({C} disjointUnion {X})) = ...
```

The only programming environment I've seen that deals with sets in any detail would be Isabelle/HOL, and I'm still not sure that you can construct pattern matches over them.

EDIT: It looks like Isabelle's `function` functionality (rather than `fun`) will let you define complex non-constructor patterns, except then you have to prove that they are used consistently, and you can't use the code generator anymore.

EDIT 2: The way I implemented similar functionality over `n` commutative, associative and transitive operators was this:

My terms were of the form `A | B | C | D`, while queries were of the form `B | C | $X`, where `$X` was permitted to match zero or more things.  I pre-sorted these using lexographic ordering, so that variables always occurred in the last position.

First, you construct all pairwise matches, ignoring variables for now, and recording those that match according to your rules.

```
{ (B,B), (C,C)  }
```

If you treat this as a bipartite graph, then you are essentially doing a [perfect marriage](http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/~simon/handouts/4245/hall.html) problem.  There exist fast algorithms for finding these.

Assuming you find one, then you gather up everything that does not appear on the left-hand side of your relation (in this example, `A` and `D`), and you stuff them into the variable `$X`, and your match is complete.  Obviously you can fail at any stage here, but this will mostly happen if there is no variable free on the RHS, or if there exists a constructor on the LHS that is not matched by anything (preventing you from finding a perfect match).

Sorry if this is a bit muddled.  It's been a while since I wrote this code, but I hope this helps you, even a little bit!

For the record, this *might* not be a good approach in all cases.  I had very complex notions of 'match' on subterms (i.e., not simple equality), and so building sets or anything would not have worked.  Maybe that'll work in your case though and you can compute disjoint unions directly.

Comment: I agree, my thinking so far on how to implement this is to convert the tuple-based representation into a set representation up front so as to be able to perform this type of query reasonably efficiently. I figured it was worth checking to see if anyone had already invented this particular wheel first, though.

Comment: I've implemented something similar in a model-checker for bigraphs.  Parallel composition for bigraphs is commutative, so I had to implement exactly this functionality.  It was mostly horrible to implement, I must say.  The code is available, but I suspect it's not going to be helpful because it's very tied up with other bigraph matching code, and unlikely to be usefully reusable.  I'll edit my answer to sketch the way I implemented it though.

Comment: The notion of sorting the list(s) of the match, and the matchee, is on of the techniques commonly used to address this problem (at least if the operator is commutive; doesn't work for only associative operators).  Mathematica uses this technique, IIRC (haven't coded in it over 15 years, so my memory's a bit foggy here).